# Running mitmproxy on macOS Sierra: traffic not passing through

Tags: mitmproxy

I have installed mitmproxy with homebrew.

```
mitmproxy --version
Mitmproxy version: 2.0.0 (release version)
Python version: 3.6.0
Platform: Darwin-16.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
SSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
Mac version: 10.12.2 ('', '', '') x86_64

mitmproxy -T --host
```

And then point a browser at mitm.it and I see the message "If you can see this, traffic is not passing through mitmproxy."  Is there a known problem or fix? If not where should I investigate?

Comment: Although old, Just adding back since i was looking for the same and found a solution

As per the documentation : On iOS 10.3 and onwards, you also need to enable full trust for the mitmproxy root certificate:
Go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings.
Under “Enable full trust for root certificates”, turn on trust for the mitmproxy certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for Android solution , and I got it working once I changed the proxy port to 8080 . I had initially set the port to 8888 for Charles proxy .

FOr the complete steps , you could follow ::

[Medium Blog to set it up](https://medium.com/sean3z/debugging-mobile-apps-with-mitmproxy-4596e56b3da2)

Or the Charles Proxy Config @ 
[Android Config](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121)

Complete Steps (taken from second link)::

1. Go to mitm.it from your device and download the MITM 
   certificate.
2. Name the certificate and okay it as a trusted certificate.
   Ensure that you disable or remove it when complete.
3. Once the certificate is installed, you are prompted to set up a PIN.
4. When prompted, add the new PIN.
5. Go to Settings > Wifi.
6. Press and hold down the power key on the Wifi Network device you are currently 
   connected to.
7. When the modal displays, select Modify Network.
8. Select Show Advanced Options to display proxying options.
9. Under Proxy, select Manual.
10. In the Proxy Host Name box, enter the IPV4 Address you previously saved from your 
    development machine.
11. In the Proxy Port field, enter 8080(this is the default port for mitm), as when 
    configuring Charles.